# dask multiprocessing with excel files

Tags: python, excel, pandas, multiprocessing, anaconda3

Hello how do i multiply 3 tables from excel files using multiprocess
with pool(Anaconda jupyter).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see the guide to [ask]. can you please pick a specific approach and show us what you've tried and what's not working? dask and multiprocessing.pool are mutually exclusive approaches. there's tons of examples on this site and elsewhere of how to read an excel file, so please give it a stab and then you're welcome to come back and ask again if you're stuck.